# SQL query optimization and sort by other row if first is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    U.nick AS author_nick,
    P.id AS post_id,
    P.name AS post_name,
    P.author AS post_author_id,
    U2.nick AS post_author
FROM 
    zero_topics T
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_posts P
ON 
    T.id = P.topic_id
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_players U
ON 
    T.author = U.uuid
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_players U2
ON 
    P.author = U2.uuid
ORDER BY 
    P.id DESC
```

Questions:

1. I need to double left join to get user nick from UUID for topic and post
2. Not all topics will have post, as you see i sort from post id(it will be date) but it shows on first place topics with last post, and on bottom topics without replies, how can i define order when posts doesn't exists?

Comment: Are you running both MySQL and MS SQL Server?

Comment: only MySQL, bad tag sql-server, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You will need to double left join if you need to show the nicks in different columns

2.You could use a `case` in you `order by`

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN P.id is null THEN T.ID
        ELSE P.ID 
    END ASC
```

Final Query:-

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    U.nick AS author_nick,
    P.id AS post_id,
    P.name AS post_name,
    P.author AS post_author_id,
    U2.nick AS post_author
FROM 
    zero_topics T
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_posts P
ON 
    T.id = P.topic_id
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_players U
ON 
    T.author = U.uuid
LEFT JOIN 
    zero_players U2
ON 
    P.author = U2.uuid
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN P.id is null THEN T.ID
    ELSE P.ID 
END ASC
```

Comment: P.id and T.id could well be different data types, say, char and int. Even if the same type, they would have no relationship with each other so the ordering would be meaningless.

Comment: You are correct and without the schema I wouldnt know what they meant or their datatypes anyways. The above sample was just to show that the OP could order by with a case statement, I am sure he would have modified it according to his needs.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two join chains from the topics table. One chain ties an author directly to the topic and one ties an author to each post about the topic, either one or both may be left joined. But once you start a left join in a chain, it must then be continued down the rest of the chain or you nullify the left join. Actually, the topic author is in a chain of length 1 so you don't have to worry about that one.

If every topic has an author, you don't need to left join the first players table (T.author = U.uuid) as that would always link. You would left join down the post chain to see topics even if they have no posts written on them.

Assuming that is what you want to see, then the `order by` clause could well stay just as you wrote it. What you would get is a list of posts, ordered by ID, with the topics scattered around however they ended up. Any topics with no posts would be clumped all either at the beginning or at the end of the result set, depending on your settings and the DBMS.

If, however, you wrote the `order by` like this:

```
order by t.Title, p.id;
```

Then you would get all the topic ordered by title, with the posts written about that topic ordered by ID within each topic. Any topic with no posts would have a single row (assuming only one topic author) in the proper title order but showing only topic data.

So it all depends on what you want to see.